# PHP - DataTables Server Side individual column filtering only gives first pages selection options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I have my DataTable set up, correctly returning data from my database and the filtering does actually work, but the problem I have is that the selection box for each column only shows values off the first page of data.

I guess I would have to do some sort of `DISTINCT` query in my PHP but I have no Idea how I would then get that in to JavaScript as well as work with DataTables.

This is what I have so far:

HTML / JS:

```
<table id="mainTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>UserID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>UserID</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>


</table>  

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#mainTable').dataTable( {

            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo url(); ?>/new/datatables.php?sSearch=1&bSearchable_0=1&bSearchable_1=1&sEcho=1&sOrder=1",

            initComplete: function () {
            var api = this.api();

            api.columns().indexes().flatten().each( function ( i ) {
                var column = api.column( i );
                var select = $('<select><option value="">All</option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search( val ? ''+val+'' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'" style="min-width:95px;">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        },


                    "aLengthMenu": [20, 10, 20, 25, 50],
                    "oLanguage": {
                    "sLoadingRecords": "<h4 style='float:left;'>Loading...</h4> <img src='<?php echo url(); ?>/img/common/loading3.gif' style='float:right;'>"
                                            },

                    "pagingType": "full_numbers",

                    "sDom": "<'container-fluid'<'span6'<'pull-left'T>><'span6'<'pull-right'f>>r>t<'clear'>rt<'container-fluid'<'span6'<'pull-left'i>><'span6'<'pull-right'p>>>",

                  "oTableTools": {
                  "sSwfPath": "<?php echo url(); ?>/new/app/DataTables/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                  "aButtons": [
                {
                    "sExtends": "csv",
                    "sFileName": "Pick Lines - *.csv",
                    "sButtonText": "Export to CSV",
                },

                {
                    "sExtends": "xls",
                    "sFileName": "Pick Lines - *.xls",
                    "sButtonText": "Export to EXCEL (xls)",
                },

                "copy", "print"

                                    ]
                    }



                } );
            } );
        </script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$serverName = ""; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    /*
     * Script:    DataTables server-side script for PHP and MySQL
     * Copyright: 2010 - Allan Jardine
     * License:   GPL v2 or BSD (3-point)
     */

    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Easy set variables
     */

    /* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
     * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
     */


    $aColumns = array( 'ID', 'UserID');

    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "ID";

    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "ActivityLog";


    /* 
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
    $sLimit = "OFFSET  ".$_GET['iDisplayStart']." ROWS 
                                FETCH NEXT ".$_GET['iDisplayLength']." ROWS ONLY "; 
    }


    /*
     * Ordering
     */

    $sOrder = ""; 
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                    ".addslashes( $_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] ) .", ";
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }


    /* 
     * Filtering
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
     */
    $sWhere = "";
    if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".addslashes( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {

        $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] = "true";
        if ( isset($_GET['sSearch_'.$i]) && !empty($_GET['sSearch_'.$i]))
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".addslashes($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
        else {
             $sWhere .= "";
        }
    }


    /*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display
     */
    $sQuery = "
SELECT ID, UserID
FROM
$sTable
                 $sWhere
                 $sOrder
                 $sLimit
    ";



    $rResult = sqlsrv_query($conn,  $sQuery ) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));

    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQueryRow = "
SELECT ID, UserID  FROM $sTable
                 $sWhere
    ";

    //echo $sQueryRow;
    $params = array();
    $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sQueryRow , $params, $options );

    $iFilteredTotal = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );



    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
        FROM   $sTable
    ";
    $rResultTotal = sqlsrv_query($conn,  $sQuery ) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
    $aResultTotal = sqlsrv_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];




    /*
     * Output
     */
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );

    while ( $aRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

The problem I am having is that this shows 39 rows, as it should, but the dropdown only shows the first 20 shows on the first page for each filter, like in this image example, 39 rows but only 1-20 to filter on the dropdown box.

[image: 1-20]

When I go on to the next page, it still just shows the first 20.

Comment: So does it look like `api.column` only selects from the current page of data?  Instead of doing it in the js, could you create the selectlist data in the server-side code & pass it when you populate the datatable?

Comment: This is what I meant with probably having to use a `DISTINCT` query, but im not sure how to populate it to the datatable.

Comment: You need to include it in the 'aaData' object. I'm not familiar with PHP, but maybe you could add a new element in the array to contain the selectlist contents.

Answer (score 4):

I did some research on this and couldn't find any example code so I came up with a solution that works fairly well. To explain how it works I created a function that makes an ajax call when the select drop down gets focused on. Also I added a where clause to the datatables php to handle display of the filtered json data.

One important thing to note is that I had to establish flow control since there is some strange behavior that happens when filtering via columns if other tabletools elements are used. My solution was to clear out the filtering selected when a table tool is used so there are a bunch of events being listened for.

HTML

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">

var where;
var selInitd = new Array();
var selectedData;

$(document).ready(function() {
   function getSelectedList(str){
    var response = new Array();
    var returnArray = new Array();
    $.ajax({
        url: "./filter.php",
        data: "selected="+str,
        async: false,
        success: function(msg){
            response = msg.split(',');
            //alert(response);
            for(m = 0; m < response.length; m++){
              response[m] = response[m].replace('[','');
              response[m] = response[m].replace(']','');
              response[m] = response[m].replace(/\"/g,'');

              var val = response[m];
              returnArray.push(val);
            }
        }
    })

    return returnArray;
   } 

   var columnNumber = $('#example thead th').length;

   //this can probably be handled in PHP 
   function colSelected(column){
    switch(column){
        case 0:
            return "columnA";
            break;
        case 1:
            return "columnB";
            break;
        case 2:
            return "columnC";
            break;
        case 3:
            return "columnD";
            break;
        case 4:
            return "columnE";
            break;
        case 5:
            return "columnF";
            break;
        case 6:
            return "columnG";
            break;
        case 7:
            return "columnH";
            break;
        case 8:
            return "columnI";
            break;  
        case 9:
            return "columnJ";
            break;  
        default:
            return "columnA";
    }
   } 

  var table = $('#example')
    .DataTable( {
        scrollX: true,
        dom: '<"top"fl>rt<"bottom"ipT><"clear">',
                serverSide: true,
        processing: true,
        ordering: true,
        order: [[ 9, "columnJ" ]],
        ajax: {
            url: "../dt.php",
            data: function ( json ){
                json.where = where;
            },
        },
        tableTools: {
            sRowSelect: "os",
            sSwfPath: "./copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            aButtons: [
                {
                  sExtends: "collection",
                  sButtonText: "Save",
                  sButtonClass: "save-collection",
                  aButtons: [ 'copy', 'csv', 'xls', 'pdf' ]
                },
                'print'
            ]
        },
        initComplete: function (settings, json) {
            var api = this.api();
            //alert(Object.keys(settings.oPreviousSearch));

            var col;

            api.columns().indexes().flatten().each( function ( i ) {
                selInitd[i] = false;
                var column = api.column( i );
                    //made the column number the id for getElementById
                var select = $('<select id=' + i + '><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        for (k = 0; k < columnNumber; k++){
                            //inefficient but gets every column selected every time any column is selected
                            var value = document.getElementById(k).value;
                            if (value != "" ){

                                //exposes the column names, you probably want to do this differently
                                col = colSelected(k);

                                //build where to send to php, you probably want to do this differently
                                if (where == null){
                                    where = col + " = '" + value + "'";
                                }else{
                                    where = where + " AND " + col + " = '" + value + "'";
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        api.ajax.reload( null, true );

                        where = null;

                    } )
                    .on( 'focus', function () {
                        if(!selInitd[i]){
                            var selectedL = getSelectedList(colSelected(i)).slice();

                            for(d = 0; d < selectedL.length; d++) {
                                select.append( '<option value="' + selectedL[d] + '">' + selectedL[d] + '</option>' )
                            }

                            selInitd[i] = true;
                        }
                    } );
             } );
        }
    } );

    //reset filter selections when text is entered in the search box
    $(".dataTables_filter input")
        .on("input.dt", function(e) {
            //reset select inputs
            for(h = 0; h < columnNumber; h++){
                var value = document.getElementById(h);
                value.selectedIndex = 0;
            }

            return;
        });

    //reset filter selections when sorting by column
    $(".dataTables_scrollHeadInner th.sorting")
        .on("click.dt", function(e) {
            //reset select inputs
            for(h = 0; h < columnNumber; h++){
                var value = document.getElementById(h);
                value.selectedIndex = 0;
            }

            return;
        });

    //reset filter selections page length widget is changed
    $(".dataTables_length select")
        .on("click.dt", function(e) {
            //reset select inputs
            for(h = 0; h < columnNumber; h++){
                var value = document.getElementById(h);
                value.selectedIndex = 0;
            }

            return;
        });

    //reset filter selections page number is changed     
    table.on("page.dt", function(e) {
        //reset select inputs
        for(h = 0; h < columnNumber; h++){
            var value = document.getElementById(h);
            value.selectedIndex = 0;
        }

        return;
    });
} );

    </script>
</head>

</body>
<div class="container">
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>columnA</th>
            <th>columnB</th>
            <th>columnC</th>
            <th>columnD</th>
            <th>columnE</th>
            <th>columnF</th>
            <th>columnG</th>
            <th>columnH</th>
            <th>columnI</th>
            <th>columnJ</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
            <th>columnA</th>
            <th>columnB</th>
            <th>columnC</th>
            <th>columnD</th>
            <th>columnE</th>
            <th>columnF</th>
            <th>columnG</th>
            <th>columnH</th>
            <th>columnI</th>
            <th>columnJ</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Filter PHP

```
<?php
$column = $_GET['selected'];

//conection: 
$link = mysqli_connect("ip.address","user","password","DB") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 

//consultation: 

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT ".$column." FROM table ORDER BY ".$column." ASC" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link)); 

//execute the query. 

$result = $link->query($query); 

//display information: 

$rows = array();
$rIdx = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
  $rows[$rIdx] =  $row[$column]; 
  $rIdx++;
} 

if($rows){
    echo json_encode($rows);
}
```

DT PHP

```
<?php

/*
 * DataTables example server-side processing script.
 *
 * Please note that this script is intentionally extremely simply to show how
 * server-side processing can be implemented, and probably shouldn't be used as
 * the basis for a large complex system. It is suitable for simple use cases as
 * for learning.
 *
 * See http://datatables.net/usage/server-side for full details on the server-
 * side processing requirements of DataTables.
 *
 * @license MIT - http://datatables.net/license_mit
 */

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Easy set variables
 */

// DB table to use
$table = 'table';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'columnA';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'columnA',   'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'columnB',   'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'columnC',   'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'columnD',   'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'columnE',   'dt' => 4 ),
    array( 'db' => 'columnF',   'dt' => 5 ),
    array( 'db' => 'columnG',   'dt' => 6 ),
    array( 'db' => 'columnH',   'dt' => 7 ),
    array( 'db' => 'columnI',   'dt' => 8 ),
    array( 'db' => 'columnJ',   'dt' => 9 )
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => 'user',
    'pass' => 'password',
    'db'   => 'DB',
    'host' => 'ip.address'
);

$whereAllClause = '';

if ($_GET['where'] != ''){
    $whereAllClause = $_GET['where'];
    $whereAllClause = str_replace('+', ' ', $whereAllClause);
    $whereAllClause = str_replace('%3D', '=', $whereAllClause);
    $whereAllClause = str_replace('%27', '\'', $whereAllClause);
}


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
 * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
 */

require( './ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::complex( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, null, $whereAllClause )
);
```